# CSS Fixed headers table in ie

Tags: html, css

can anyone help me out with creating fixed headers on a table using css only (no js).  It needs to support dynamic data as the column sizes are coming from a db.  Only needs to work in ie7/8. Cheers

Comment: I've tried setting overflow on the tbody but doesn't seem to work in ie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decide to go with JS (as I'm pretty sure this is hardly possible with sheer CSS), you can try my [script](http://code.google.com/p/js-scroll-table-header/). See a [demo](http://outro.lt/sth-demo.html). It's cross browser and optimized for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're trying to create a table where you can scrollthe body part and have the first (header) row not move. This can be done by having one table with the header row, and a second placed inside a `<div style="max-height: 400px; overflow: auto;">` - note that this will only work with fixed-width columns, unless you use JavaScript.

If this is not what you're trying to achieve, please disregard this post.

Comment: Instead of using two tables you can use <thead> and <tbody>

Comment: @MatTheCat: Can you give a demo how to keep the `thead` in a fixed position?

Comment: Hi Kolink, yes that's what I'm trying to achieve, however columns are not fixed width and I would rather not use any javascript

Comment: Found, you just have to set explicit height for <tbody>, position:absolute and overflow:auto.

Comment: Although it's a gross hack, you can use two tables, identical in content, with thead and tbody. Set the tbody of the 'head' one to `display:none`, put the other one in a scrolling div (as you suggested) and then `display:none` on the thead. This way the content in both tables will keep the column widths the same. (It's been a while since I did this; it may be that you need `visibility:hidden` instead to ensure the items are included for sizing.)

Comment: @Phrogz: *LOL* If `display:none` doesn't work on `thead`, you can fall back to hide the individual rows so your solution should work anywhere. If you copy the table with JavaScript, it's not even very expensive (network and/or CPU wise).

Answer (score 0):

So that is what I thought :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

tbody {
    max-height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
    position:absolute;
}
tr td:last-child { /* do horizontal scrollbar useless */
    padding-right:1em;
}
```

EDIT: raaah it works on IE8 but not IE7 (tested with IE9 beta), it seems IE7 applies height rule to `<td>` elements!

Comment: Do you have IE8 true version?

Comment: I assume you mean a non beta version, then yes

Comment: IE9 can only mimic so many bugs from IE8... ;-) if you suggest a solution for IE*, you better try that with that exact version. And possibly with all service packs. And on different versions of Windows.